# Start approval process action in sharepoint designer workflow 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity

I'm using SharePoint designer 2010,
I have create workflow.
in the workflow I'm using the "Start Approval Process" action.
I bump into an error when I operate this action:

[image: Action Error]

how I need to configure this action in order to avoid the error?

basically I need to send a list item to approve/reject from one user, is there some other way to implement it?

Comment: Do you have Content Approval enabled on the list?